# Gerrit trigger Custom build messages

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

How to send a custom message to Gerrit with the `Custom build messages` field in the Gerrit trigger options in Jenkins?

The setting of the location is on *job properties* -> *gerrit trigger* -> *advanced*

I have defined a in the `Build Start Message` field: *My custom message*

I would expect to se this message in Gerrit, however no comment is shown. If i remove the custom message, il leaves the default comment for the Start message.

Should the Custom build messages be pure strings or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the whole system after which the `Custom build message` field started acting as expected.

It seems the problem was that i edited the message in the global `Gerrit Verified Commands` before (i did however return it to default settings before trying Custom build message)

Comment: Hi Alan, did you ever find the root cause? I'm facing the same issue but a restart did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Nope, just did a reinstall and it started working.
Try looking at the console output Jenkins produces (if you're running it as a .war file from the console, don't know where that's located if you do install with apt/yum)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the message in the global gerrit trigger settings: jenkins->manage->gerrit trigger

Then under the advanced section you can see the Gerrit Verified Commands that the gerrit trigger uses to update gerrit. This is what I see for the started event:

```
gerrit approve <CHANGE>,<PATCHSET> --message 'Build Started <BUILDURL> <STARTED_STATS>' --verified <VERIFIED> --code-review <CODE_REVIEW>
```

You should be able to change the message there.

Comment: This defines the message on a global scale for all projects. What I'm looking for is per project basis.